# ERROR ITMS-90283: "Invalid Provisioning Profile"

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos, xcode8

I have inherited an old macos app and I am trying to upload a new version to the app store. When trying to upload the new build, i keep getting this error:

```
ERROR ITMS-90283: "Invalid Provisioning Profile. The provisioning profile included in the bundle com.****.**** [com.****.****.pkg/Payload/****.app] is invalid. [Invalid 'com.apple.application-identifier' entitlement value.] For more information, visit the macOS Developer Portal."
```

I have trying creating new certificates, but i'm not sure what i am doing wrong. How do i upload a new build to a protect i have just been given access to?

Comment: @ user2097028 Do you get the solution?

Comment: Any solution found?

Answer (score 2):

(https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/qa/qa1878/_index.html) :

Q: What causes the provisioning profile "Invalid" status? How do I resolve it, and how do I prevent it?

A: The provisioning profile invalid status is caused by changes to the profile’s associated certificate or App ID. Any time an App ID or certificate changes, all profiles that are associated to it are marked Invalid. This does not apply to Xcode's team profiles, but applies to all profiles that Xcode does not manage, specifically, custom development profiles and distribution profiles. This document explains the causes in detail and provides steps to resolve and avoid the profile invalid status.

Answer (score 0):

I experienced this issue when I enabled in-app purchasing on my application and was manually signing my application through codesign command line.

Switching back to using Xcode Organizer to submit my application seems to have resolved the issue.